# Facebook App: Displaying Users Photos to Other Users?

Tags: facebook, permissions, fbml, photo, xfbml

Does anyone know if Facebook Permissions will allow an app to display a photo of one app user to another, regardless of privacy settings?

I want to save photo id's to a database and then display many different users photos at once, to the user, within the app.

I could use fbml but am hoping to use xfbml.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook API restrictions are going to be exactly the same as the authenticated user ( assuming they grant you sufficient access).  So if a user has access to photo's in another users gallery, you can display them.  If they don't, you cannot.

However, if you save the Photo ID of a users picture, then want to display it to a different user later on, who does not have implicit rights to view that photo, they will not be able to see it.

Your app would be best served by taking a copy of the shared photo, which would take Facebook permissions completely out of the equation.